# Regex Pattern that Looks for a String between two Specified Strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file, and I extract a line in C# out of it that looks like this:

```
Date: 8/20/2013 12:00:00 AM Source Path: \\build\PM\11.0.25.9\ Destination Path: C:\Users\Documents\testing\11.0.25.9\etc\ Folder Updated: 11.0.25.9 File Copied: 11052_0_X.pts
```

The easiest way to extract what variables I need would be to create a regex pattern to look for it.

So lets say i'm trying to extract the source path out of this line of text. 
How would I create a pattern that will look for a string inbetween the two strings. Such as how do I extract the source path string from between "Source Path:" and "Destination Path:"?

All I have so far is this:
    Regex.Match(line,@"Source Path:");

To test this out im using http://regexhero.net/tester/ and clearly all it does is look for the Source Path: so far. How could I look ahead until the string "Destination Path:"?

Comment: If you are unsure how regexes work (and you are), why not use two calls to `IndexOf()` and one to `Substring()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string input = @"Date: 8/20/2013 12:00:00 AM Source Path: \\build\PM\11.0.25.9\ Destination Path: C:\Users\Documents\testing\11.0.25.9\etc\ Folder Updated: 11.0.25.9 File Copied: 11052_0_X.pts";
string pattern = @"Source Path:(.+?)Destination Path:";

var src = Regex.Match(input,pattern).Groups[1].Value.Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var path = Regex.Match(line, @"Source Path:\s*(.*)\s*Destination Path:")
                .Groups[1].Value;
```

Or this (using lookaround assertions):

```
var path = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<=Source Path:\s*).*(?=\s*Destination Path:)")
                .Value;
```

But for something this simple, you don't really regular expressions. This will work just as well:

```
var startAt = "Source Path:";
var endAt = "Destination Path:";

var start = line.IndexOf(startAt);
var end   = line.IndexOf(endAt);
if (start >= 0 && end >= 0 && (end >= start + startAt.Length))
{
    var path = line.Substring(start + startAt.Length, 
                              end - start - startAt.Length).Trim();
}
```

Comment: Except that the IndexOf/Substring version is wrong (returns `\\build\PM\11.0.25.9\ Destination`, _before you fixed it_) and lacks any error checking whatsoever, making it evilly wrong. This is why you write code that expresses intent, instead of writing brittle index manipulations :)

Comment: @sehe That's a valid point about error checking, but I don't understand why you say this is more brittle than the regex. It's just as dependent upon the input as the regex pattern would be.

Comment: Arhem? You got it wrong the first time, have magic constants (_not repeated anymore, now: kudos_), no error checking means you'll get `ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Cannot be negative.` if `end` is -1, but silently wrong results if `start` is `11` _[sic]_. How is that _not_ brittle?

Comment: IOW: It's brittle because it doesn't just dependend on the input, it depends on it containing specific substrings in specific orders and has no well-defined failure modes otherwise. _The regex would just return `.Success==false`. Also, the regex expresses in a single string the intent to capture `(.*?)` inside the two texts._

Comment: @sehe Yes I agree about the error checking (by index-based code was intended to be a starting point not the complete solution), and I agree that regex is a generally more flexible solution. But when I see a question like 'find a single substring between this fixed and this fixed input', regex is just trading out one two magical constants for one and introducing a lot more potential complexity in the code. I'd probably go with regular expressions in my own code, depending on the situation, but the simpler solution should at least be considered, IMO.

Comment: Tell me again how the simpler solution was simpler? It wasn't even complete, and making it complete would be... not so simple :) Anyways, +1 for the rest of the answer. I take the comments as sufficient warning for passers-by

Comment: Amusingly, I'll fix another error in your updated code :/ (really, they were three, in a single line)